# Specifications for input image

Tags: graphics

I need to specify a specific location for a picture. Are there any options for this in LaTex? The picture should be specified with something like: 2cm from top and 3 cm from left side.The reason for this is that i need to print the document to some labels.

Comment: Do you know package [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos)?

Comment: So, your picture is not going to be a float? About your second part, are you going prepare some kind of printed label? And welcome to tex.SE.

Comment: I will take a look at the textpos package. Yes, iam going to print some pdf's to labels. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Place the image in the page head (or straight after `\clearpage`) so it is at a fixed position, then

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(100,200){\includegraphics{...}
\end{picture}
```

The `(0,0)` means the image takes no space, the `(100,200)`  can be adjusted to position the image anywhere (default unit 1pt`)

Comment: By loading the `picture` package one can also specify coordinates using the normal units; for instance `\put(1cm,2cm){...}`